# Solve $\tan(2t)=1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

My textbook is listing solutions to this equation as $2t=\pm \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $2t=\pm \frac{5\pi}{4}$ however this doesn't seem correct at all, I believe the only solutions should be $2t=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $2t=\frac{5\pi}{4}$ since the other solutions will result in $\tan(2t)=-1$

In case it's of any importance this came from parameterizing $x^2+y^2<1$ with $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$ and then plugging these into $f(x,y)=xy-y^2$ to obtain $g(t)=\frac{1}{2}(\sin 2t+\cos 2t+1)$ and then attempting to solve for when max/min occur.

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: You are right, $2t=-\pi/4$ is not a solution of $\tan(2t)=1$.

Comment: Weird, if anyone is curious it is question #3 from section 13.2 in Calculus, A Complete Course 8th edition -R. Adams

Comment: The full set of solutions is $2t\equiv \frac\pi4\mod\pi$, i.e. $t\equiv \frac\pi8\mod\frac\pi2$.

Comment: @Bernard Do you know whether the OP knows some elementary number theory or no?

Comment: That's high school  notation, not really number theory.

Comment: I think it varies from one high school to another! By the way I like your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right but the better solution is $2t=\pi/4+k\pi, k\in \mathbb{Z}. $